# Allowing a WPF browser application to navigate to a separate web page when finished?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF browser application that collects user data and adds it to a database to tell them when their software is out of date.

All of that works fine, but the problem is when the application finishes its stuff, I want the web page itself to change (i.e., detect the web app has hit a 'finished' state, then autonagivate to a results page or something).

I can't think of a way to accomplish this, since the web app itself doesn't seem to be able to change the IFRAME it's contained in, much less the page outside of that, or signal to javascript or anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd make an variable to keep progress/step of work. And a timer which would check if progress=="done" or sth.

Maybe this is not the best way of solving this but I don't know WPF much and that solution first came to mind

Comment: A progress variable in the WPF app? That's not externally visible to Javascript, or anything really (WPF browser apps run in PresentationHost.exe, there's no actual script on the page as far as I know)